# database selecting cell values from different tuples connected by id

Tags: mysql

I have info table in which three columns are present named as id , name , manager_id. name gives name of employe and manager_id gives who is manager of that employee.

Example: In below shown table 'alex' is employee whose manager is 'peter' similarly for others.

My problem is to select name of employee and name of his manager. Ex : Peter,kristen or alex,peter etc. But I am not able find solution for this. I tried nested queries but without luck.

```
mysql> select * from info;
+------+---------+------------+
| id   | name    | manager_id |
+------+---------+------------+
|    1 | abraham |       NULL |
|    2 | kristen |          1 |
|    3 | peter   |          2 |
|    4 | alex    |          3 |
+------+---------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from info a ,info b where a.name='alex' and a.id=b.manager_id

Comment: It is returning empty. By the way how can 'alex' name be constant in query.

Comment: if you don't want to constant name than plz remove a.name='alex' in where clouse
eg . "select a.id,a.name,b.name as manager from test a ,test b where a.id=b.manager_id"